# Taking objects from literal with many objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular.js

I have data returned from an API coming back in a response: `response.data`

```
[
    {"amount":"45342",
    "comment":"random text",
    "currency":"USD"},
    {"city":"LA",
    "amount":"54366",
    "lane_id":{"$oid":"5645999965a5b0"}}
]
```

I need to take only the amount and create a new set of objects like this:
`[{amount: "45342"}, {amount: "54366"}]`

The obvious way would be to push it through a loop like so:

```
var newArray = [];
var newObject;
var i, len;
for (len = response.data.length, i=0; i<len; ++i){
  newObject = response.data[i];
  newArray.push({amount: newObject.amount});
};
```

Is there a better way? I am running on angular 1.5 and jquery

Comment: You can use [`array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `map` function provided for all arrays. You would need to make sure that `response.data` always returns an array, even in the case where nothing was returned from the api otherwise you can get an error.

```
var newArray = response.data.map(function(data) { 
  return {amount: data.amount}
});
```

would get you what you are looking for.